# Like / Dislike Button

Tags: views, nodes, flags, rating

I need to like AND to dislike contenttyps, but the total likes should be displayed as Likes - Dislikes. I tried to use the "flag" module and created two different flags (one for likes, one for dislikes) but this leaves me with two problems

1. I need to get the total count of the likes (likes - dislikes) within a view - how can I do this??
2. Can I disable the like/dislike button, if it was already clicked? So you can like and dislike but only once (no toggle).

Comment: Have you looked at the [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) module?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to customize the excellent tutorial on the use of [Ajax for Like and Dislike using voting API](http://amitavroy.com/justread/content/articles/ajax-and-dislike-using-voting-api-drupal) by Amitav Roy. His primary purpose is to show the reader how to use AJAX, but the code is solid and seems to suit your purpose.

Comment: Thx, I was hoping for a simpler way to do this - but if I can't find anything I'm going to try this out.